# Can't establish connection to SQL Server running in Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have to use SQL Server for a fresh Laravel project. My host machine is macOS Big Sur.

In my `docker-compose.yml` I've replaced `mysql` with `mssql` and filled everything with what I've googled so far:

So my `services/mssql` chunk looks like:

```
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    volumes:
      - ./docker/volumes/mssql:/var/opt/mssql
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "Test123456789"
    ports:
      - 11433:1433
    networks:
      - local_network
```

The volume is set correctly (to make data persistent).

[image]

When I build it via `docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate` I get errors. Building is finished, green done and containers are up and running.

So now on my host machine I've installed free client called Azure Data Studio to connect to the DB. Same stuff I do with MySQL and Sequel Ace.

So I create new connection. I assume that server is `127.0.0.1` and port is the port `11433` which I've specified earlier.

So in the connection details - server input I gave `127.0.0.1:11433`.

Username is `sa` and password is from `SA_PASSWORD` which is `Test123456789`. I'm getting some kind of timeout issue.

What am I doing wrong?

The error is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

More details: https://gist.github.com/mattkomarnicki/d9bca0069aa440193d438ebee3c05ef1

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with my question? Why you want to close it?

Comment: Can you pop the error message in your question as text, not an image, please?

Comment: Try adding `net=host` https://docs.docker.com/network/host/ (this should expose your container to your local machine, not just to other containers in the composition)

Comment: Also your question mentions you tried connecting on `127.0.0.1:11433` which has an additional digit in the port number. Is that a typo?

Comment: @gvee I've added details into the question content.

Comment: No typo: in docker you specify host port and container port: `11433:1433`. Hence `11433`.

Comment: Try `host.docker.internal:11433` - I have to do this on a Windows machine.

Comment: Depending on the underlying driver sometimes you need to use `server,port` in your connection string instead of `server:port`. i.e.: have you tried `127.0.0.1,11433`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my! Microsoft stack is so odd!

In Azure Data Studio in the connection server name instead of `127.0.0.1:11433` I had to provide `127.0.0.1, 11433`.

[image]

Now I'm connected.

[image]